# Powershell windows server 2012 .Path Error installing Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP)

Tags: python, powershell, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to install Hadoop for Windows  (Hortonworks Data Platform 2.0), in a windows server 2012 enviroment, and creating the next powershell command

```
$currentPath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -name) .Path + ';'
```

I get this error

```
At line:1 char:52
+$currentPath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -name) .Path + ';'
+
Unexpected toke '.Path' in expression or statement
   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError:(:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorID : UnexpectedToken
```

What am I doing wrong, keep in mind that I'm going this oficial documentation by Horton Works

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-Win-latest/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-softwareinstall-ps.html#win-cli-python

Answer (score 0):

Let's see,

To start, you have a space here ) .Path

Secondly Path does not appear to be a valid property returned by that cmdlet so even once you correct the errant space it will still not work

Thirdly, you are specifying the parameter -name without providing a value

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I was able to solve the error.

Here's the thing, what I was trying to do, is installing the HDP enviroment in Windows Server using PowerShell, and since I'm not very good at it, I make dumb errors.

For those who are not very good using the powershell there's a manual way to install the required enviroment for HDP, that's far more simple.

Here's the link.

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-Win-latest/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-software-install-gui.html

I hope it can't save a bit more time.